# How to Show Image from Restful Service to Xamarin.Forms View with MVVM

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, mvvm, service

I have a Restful Service which provides me Image as a stream. When I call that service into the browser to show image it works well there too.
Now I am trying to show that image in the Xamarin View like this:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="200"></ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

ViewModel contains the following functionality:

```
private ImageSource _imageSource;
public ImageSource ImageSource
{
    get { return _imageSource; }
    set
    {
        _imageSource = value;
        SetProperty(ref _imageSource, value);
    }
}
private string itemId;
public string ItemId
{
    get
    {
        return itemId;
    }
    set
    {
        itemId = value;
        LoadItemId(value);
    }
}

public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)
{
    try
    {
        var item = await MockDataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
        Id = item.ID;
        Text = item.TITLE;
        Description = item.CONTENT;
        //ImageSource = "http://127.0.0.1:4321/Service.svc/GetImage/?uri=12";
        ImageSource = "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/05/02/758874_package_512x512.png";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
    }
}
```

When I provide image link directly in the Source of the image in view it works perfectly.

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/05/02/758874_package_512x512.png" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="200"></ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

But when I try to get ImageSource from ViewModel, none is showing image on view neither the service call nor any image link.
The strange thing which I have seen while debugging is that whenever I change anything in the view which activates the *Hot Reload* it suddenly shows the image from ViewModel in the emulator.
I am new to Xamarin and don't know how to get it resolved.

Comment: `Source="{Binding ImageSource}"` - where is the `ImageSource` property in your VM?

Comment: Is `ImageSource` a dependency property?

Comment: I think its not a Dependency property. I have updated the question for **ImageSource** Property
@ΩmegaMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VM doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, put that in place and signal the change to `ImageSource` for the view/xaml.

Comment: actually VM is inherited from a `BaseViewModel` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`  as follows:
`public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: the strange thing is that whenever I make any change in View the `Hot Reload` suddenly shows the image in emulator. Any other changes are being performed from VM
`Id = item.ID;`
`Text = item.TITLE;`
`Description = item.CONTENT;`

Comment: To be clear `SetProperty(ref _imageSource, value);` is notifying the NotifyPropertyChanged event right?

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro, I just changed the property name from `ImageSource` to `ImgSource` and changed the format of the `Property` as:
`private ImageSource _imageSource;`
`public ImageSource ImgSource`
`{`
     `get =>_imageSource;`
     `set => SetProperty(ref _imageSource, value);`
`}`
It is now activating the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and worked!